# Change color in table Javascript

Tags: javascript, colors

(this is my first question so please be understanding how I am doing something wrong)
Hello, I have a bingo program in the form of a table in which random numbers are written, but I want the drawn number to be highlighted in the table in some color, does anyone know how to do it? the point is that if we draw the number "2", the square with this number should change color

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Bingo</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        div {
            text-align: center;
        }

        .bigNumberDisplay {
            font-size: 6em;
        }

        .numbersTable {
            font-size: 1.6em;
        }

        table {
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }

        table, tr, td {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            border: solid 1px #999;
        }

        td {
            min-width: 100px;
            color: #fff;
        }

        td.selected {
            color: #000000;
        }

    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var bingo = {
                selectedNumbers:[],
                generateRandom:function () {
                    var min = 1; //Liczba początkowa
                    var max = 89; //Liczba końcowa 
                    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
                    return random;
                },
                generateNextRandom:function () {
                    if (bingo.selectedNumbers.length > 88) {
                        alert("Koniec");
                        return 0;
                    }
                    var random = bingo.generateRandom();
                    while ($.inArray(random, bingo.selectedNumbers) > -1) {
                        random = bingo.generateRandom();
                    }
                    bingo.selectedNumbers.push(random);
                    return random;
                }
            };
            $('td').each(function () {
                var concatClass = this.cellIndex + "" + this.parentNode.rowIndex;
                var numberString = parseInt(concatClass, 10).toString();
                $(this).addClass("cell" + numberString).text(numberString);
            });
            $('#btnGenerate').click(function () {
                var random = bingo.generateNextRandom().toString();
                $('.bigNumberDisplay span').text(random);
                $('td.cell' + random).addClass('selected');
            });
            window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
                e = e || window.event;
                var returnString = 'Are you sure?';
                if (e) {
                    e.returnValue = returnString;
                }
                return returnString;
            };
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="bigNumberDisplay">
        <span>0</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input id="btnGenerate" type="button" value="Wylosuj numer stolika"/>
    </div>

    <br/>

    <div class="numbersTable">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <br/>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i'm not familiar with the game but the button executes twice , is it working correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make two changes assign a custom attribute,let's call it *CellValue*(you can call it whatever you want), containing the text of the cell to each `td`

```
  $("td").each(function () {
    var concatClass = this.cellIndex + "" + this.parentNode.rowIndex;
    var numberString = parseInt(concatClass, 10).toString();
    $(this)
      .addClass("cell" + numberString)
      .text(numberString);
    $(".cell" + numberString).attr("CellValue", numberString);
  });
```

and on button click check each table data `CellValue` to see if it matches the random generated number if it does change the background color of that `td`

```
$("#btnGenerate").click(function () {
    var random = bingo.generateNextRandom().toString();
    $(".bigNumberDisplay span").text(random);
    $("td.cell" + random).addClass("selected");
    $("td").each(function () {
      if ($(this).attr("CellValue") === random) {
        $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
      }else {
        $(this).css("background-color", "white");
      }
    });
  });
```

**Working Example:**

```js
$(function () {
  var bingo = {
    selectedNumbers: [],
    generateRandom: function () {
      var min = 1; //Liczba początkowa
      var max = 89; //Liczba końcowa
      var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
      return random;
    },
    generateNextRandom: function () {
      if (bingo.selectedNumbers.length > 88) {
        alert("Koniec");
        return 0;
      }
      var random = bingo.generateRandom();
      while ($.inArray(random, bingo.selectedNumbers) > -1) {
        random = bingo.generateRandom();
      }
      bingo.selectedNumbers.push(random);
      return random;
    },
  };
  $("td").each(function () {
    var concatClass = this.cellIndex + "" + this.parentNode.rowIndex;
    var numberString = parseInt(concatClass, 10).toString();
    $(this)
      .addClass("cell" + numberString)
      .text(numberString);
    $(".cell" + numberString).attr("CellValue", numberString);
  });
  $("#btnGenerate").click(function () {
    var random = bingo.generateNextRandom().toString();
    $(".bigNumberDisplay span").text(random);
    $("td.cell" + random).addClass("selected");
    $("td").each(function () {
      if ($(this).attr("CellValue") === random) {
        $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
      }else {
        $(this).css("background-color", "white");
      }
    });
  });
  window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var returnString = "Are you sure?";
    if (e) {
      e.returnValue = returnString;
    }
    return returnString;
  };
});
```

```css
div {
  text-align: center;
}

.bigNumberDisplay {
  font-size: 6em;
}

.numbersTable {
  font-size: 1.6em;
}

table {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

table,
tr,
td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: solid 1px #999;
}

td {
  min-width: 100px;
  color: #fff;
}

td.selected {
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title> Bingo</title>
  <link href="./index.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.js"></script>

  <script src="./index.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="bigNumberDisplay">
      <span>0</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input id="btnGenerate" type="button" value="Wylosuj numer stolika" />
    </div>

    <br />

    <div class="numbersTable">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>

    <br />

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```